# values() of a Enum

Tags: java, enums

Why I cannot see the `values` method when browsing the java.lang.Enum source code? I am using Intellij 2017.1.1 and JDK 1.8.0_131

Also, why is this method `static`? I would have expected to be an instance method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't see it because it is not defined on the `Enum` class, but rather on specific subclasses of `Enum` (i.e. your `enum`'s class).

This is because static methods are not polymorphic: a `values` method on the subclass would not override the method in the superclass, but rather hide it.

You can get the enum constants for a class reflectively:

```
YourEnum.class.getEnumConstants()
```